# Is there any point to the Jaghut Tyrant being awakened, when Lord of Galayn was ready?

Tags: malazan

In the book Gardens of the Moon we find that the Empress has sent Adjunct Lorn to awaken the Jaghut Tyrant in an effort to weaken Lord Anomander Rake. However we later find that she had a Lord of Galayn demon stored that was considered an equal to Anomander.

Is there any reason why they awoke the Jaghut Tyrant then? Other than to forward a bit of plot and have some sorcery battles go down? It seems the Tyrant was quite a big worry throughout the book, but then didn't really achieve much?

Just a note, I've only read the first book, so if this is revealed later, then it's understandable. But other than that it seems like a pointless plot device that's never used.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but it's worth keeping in mind that GotM was written 10+ years before the other books and there ends up being a lot of inconsistencies and discrepancies between character intentions in GotM vs. the rest of the series.  That being said, it gets a lot better from Deadhouse Gates on.

Comment: it was because they didnt want to waste a demon on rake, when they could simply release something else. plus didnt the demon get the crap beat out of him by rake anyways. the jaghut would have been far more powerful then the galayn demon, i believe the demon was the contingency plan should rake actually defeat the jaghut.

Comment: as a side-note, keep on reading the books. Erikson's vast world and amount of characters and story-lines make many people give up on the series, especially in the first few books, but the epic scale of the series is just wonderful. Don't stop reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really handled later in the books. The reason that both the demon and Raest were used is that the Empress wanted to make sure of Anomander's destruction; they were uncertain as to the full extent of his power so they had to make sure he was sufficiently weakened. That being said, Rake only battled the demon, where Raest was dealt with by Silanah and Anomander Rake's Tiste Andii sorcerers, and then finally captured by the Azath.

Raest was very powerful, and would have achieved much, but his release was anticipated and he was dealt with by a number of powerful characters.

Answer (score 1):

The plan was for Raest to head to the city, and with Rake being allied with it he would have to stand in the way. If Raest got to his finnest then its likely he would have defeated Rake.  Rake was prepared to fight it, because he couldn't let a powerful being run around like that, give it a few centuries and the entire continent would have been enslaved like it was before Raest was defeated.

No matter who won, the winner would be hurt badly, then the Lord of the Galayn demon would have finished them off, paving the way for the empire to take over.